# Redirect all subdomains to root domain

Tags: htaccess, subdomains

I use WordPress and would like to redirect all non-existing subdomains (or all subdomains) to the main domain.

**Examples of urls to be redirected:**

- `subdomains.example.com`
- `subdomains.example.com/xxx`
- `subdomains.example.com/xxx.html`
- `subdomains.example.com/t/xxx.php`

**TO**

`www.example.com`

This is my default WordPress `.htaccces` of the main domain (I am editing this). Any folders or files for non-existing subdomains do not exist.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Check this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/102851/73879

Comment: this is useless @Fayaz

Comment: It's not useless, you simply failed to understand it. if you use `not` operator `!` like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$`, it'll take care of all the subdomains.  Anyways, I would answer your question to the point, but this question is off topic here.

Comment: Also, before it can be used, you must point all subdomains with `*.example.com` to point to your main domain from your DNS setting.

Comment: so this is not the best solution if I need to point every domain in DNS settings. I would be grateful if you could post your exact htacces code with the dns remark. It will help thousands of wordpress users !

Comment: You want `subdomain.example.com/xyz` to redirect to `example.com` or `example.com/xyz`? Also, what do you want with `www.example.com/xyz`?

Comment: 'subdomain.example.com/xyz' to redirect to 'www.example.com' :)

Answer (score 1):

The following `.htaccess` will only work if the `subdomain` is assigned in your DNS setting using either a single DNS record or a wildcard DNS record. If your DNS setting doesn't have that record, request to your subdomain will not reach to your server. So the `.htaccess` will not work.

If you don't know how to edit DNS record, then ask your web hosting provider. Then use the following `.htaccess` CODE:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # the following three lines will work for all subdomains
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule . "http://www.example.com/" [R=301,L]

    # the following two lines will redirect non-www to www version of the domain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.example.com/$1" [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```